# How do I make a mailto: form in my HTML file?

Tags: html

I am making a website and am using Notepad++. How do I make a mailto form in my HTML document?

Thanks, Andrew

Comment: Stack Overflow is a very poor replacement for Google.

Answer (score 1):

You use the mailto function thats built in. To use it in a form you do;

```
  <form name="your name" class="your class" action="mailto:someone@example.com"> 
    </form>
```

you then need to add the address you want the form to be emailed to.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Send e-mail to someone@example.com:</h2>

<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```